# Добавить новое поле в модель

Tags: yii2

```
public function fields()
{
  $fields = parent::fields();

  // удаляем поля, содержащие конфиденциальную информацию
  unset($fields['auth_key'], $fields['password_hash'], $fields['password_reset_token']);

  return $fields;
}
```

в коде выше удаляются указанные поля методом unset().
Есть ли метод типа set() который добавляет новое поле?
Если сделать так:

```
$fields = ['requests_count'];
```

то возвращает только поле requests_count.
 Мне надо чтобы requests_count добавился к уже существующим полям

Comment: ...`array_push`....`array_merge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Естественно, `$fields = ['requests_count'];` заменяет всё содержимое массива на requests_count. Вы ведь присваиваете переменной $field новый массив. Чтобы добавить новое поле в массив нужно использовать такой синтаксис: `$fields[] = 'requests_count';`. Это добавит элемент в конец массива (с числовым индексом, который следует за наибольшим существующим индексом в массиве).

---

Если нужно добавить сразу несколько элементов, то можно использовать функцию array_push. Но для добавления в массив только одного элемента лучше не использовать функции, как советуется в документации php ([PHP: array_push - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php)).

Comment: Спасибо! Если так добавит поле то сортировка не работает?  типа orderBy('requests_count')

Comment: @IDL метод для сортировки orderBy относится не к классу модели, а к классу запроса (обычно, ActiveQuery). Объект этого класса возвращается методом find() класса ActiveRecord (это класс, унаследованный от Model). И в метод OrderBy должно передаваться имя существующего в БД атрибута, а не имя поля. (Ну или псевдоним, объявленный в секции select SQL-запроса.) Ну а о полях модели метод сортировки ничего не знает.

Comment: @IDL Поля модели вообще нужны для того, чтобы скрыть, какие данные и как там внутри хранятся. Имя добавляемого поля может совпадать с именем атрибута в БД. В своём ответе я описал добавление именно таких полей, имя которых совпадает с именем атрибута. Тогда сортировка методом orderBy должна работать.

Comment: @IDL Но имени поля может не соответствовать атрибут в базе данных. Имя поля может быть псевдонимом для атрибута в БД. Или вообще значение поля может вычисляться на основе нескольких атрибутов. В таких случаях в OrderBy нужно использовать имена атрибутов точно как в базе данных. Как я уже писал, OrderBy ничего не знает о полях модели.